# How to wrap arbitrary HTML with a wrapper without breaking markup?

Tags: html, block, inline

I have the following HTML

```
some text [selected HTML] more text
```

And I want to wrap the [selected HTML] part with a marker element so a) I can apply some markup (color it lightblue) and b) so I can find it with jQuery and C) so I can mark it for the server when I send all HTML to the server. How could I do that without changing how the page looks?

If I use a DIV element, that would create a block element which I do definitely not want if the arbitrary HTML is just text.

```
some text 
<div>[selected HTML which is text]</div>
more text
```

If I use a SPAN element (even with `style='display:inline-block'`), then I would assume that the arbitrary HTML is inline, which I cannot assume. Wrapping a `SPAN` around a `DIV` is invalid, no?

```
some text 
<span style='inline-block;'>[selected HTML with <div>]</span>
more text
```

Is there anything that I can use that simply 'marks' the HTML but does not create a block or inline element around it?

Comment: Define 'breaking markup'.  Why is avoiding invalid HTML more important than solving the problem you have here?  I'm not saying it isn't, just want to be clear on your priorities.

Comment: I agree, more context would be really helpful.

Comment: Hmm. Good question. On the client-side, I don't really care about validity. I just need to be able to refer to the arbitrary HTML with eg jQuery. I also need to send these markers to the server. But when the HTML is sent to the server, the server uses some HTML parsing and it only allows valid HTML.
Now I'm thinking: I might use a <span style="display: inline-block"/> on the client (invalid HTML but works properly) and then replace it with a <div> when I send it to the server... Hmm.

Comment: I also updated the question...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is an element that “simply 'marks' the HTML but does not create a block or inline element around it”, namely the [`ins`](http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/struct/text.html#edef-ins) element. Syntactically, the `ins` and `del` elements “may serve as either block-level or inline elements (but not both). They may contain one or more words within a paragraph or contain one or more block-level elements such as paragraphs, lists and tables”.

In principle, `ins` denotes content that has been “inserted […] with respect to a different version of a document”. But I don’t think any software takes this seriously, *except* in the sense that modern browsers generally underline the content by default. But such behavior (which is encouraged in the CSS 2.1 spec and the HTML5 drafts) can be overridden, with the usual CSS caveats, rather simply:

```
ins { text-decoration: none; }
```

Comment: Interesting, and yes it seems this does indeed validate: `<ins><div><p>Hello <ins><span>World!</span></ins></p></div></ins>` I would suggest adding a class to the `ins` and "unsetting" the styles that way, in case `ins` may be used "legitimately" somewhere else.

Comment: On another note, it's possible that HTML *comments* as delimiters possibly could have served the author, if not for the fact that he wants these sections styled with CSS as well. Might end up a little hacky and difficult anyways... but yeah - nice answer!

Comment: Apart from the semantic discussion we could have over using <ins>, this does pretty much what I want! It turns out to be the 'transparent content model' that's key here. See http://www.html-5.com/tags/element-content-models.html#transparent-content-model and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Content_categories for more information :-)